# print results in a matrix-like style with system calls

Tags: c, system-calls, matrix-multiplication

I need to print out the result of a matrix multiplication using only system calls. I get the proper results but not in the appropriate format. I get 1000x1000 rows but I'd need 1000 colums x 1000 rows. Any idea how to do it?

This is the code I've written:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define N 1000

// Matrix 
long long int A[N][N],B[N][N],R[N][N];

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int x,y,z;
    char str[100];

    /* Matrix inicialization */
    for(y=0;y<N;y++) 
        for(x=0;x<N;x++)
        {
            A[y][x]=x;
            B[y][x]=y;
            R[y][x]=0;  
        }

    /* Matrix multiplication */
    for(y=0;y<N;y++)
        for(z=0;z<N;z++) 
            for(x=0;x<N;x++) 
            {
                R[y][x]+= A[y][z] * B[z][x];    
            }

   /* Printing result */
    for(y=0;y<N;y++)
        for(x=0;x<N;x++)
        {
            sprintf(str, "%lli\n", R[y][x]);
            write(1, str, strlen(str));
        }

    exit(0);
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Change the `sprintf()` to separate numbers with spaces.  Add braces around the body of the outer `for` loop; add `putchar('\n');` after the inner `for` loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the `sprintf()` to separate numbers with spaces, and output a newline at the end of each row of the matrix:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define N 1000

// Matrix
long long int A[N][N], B[N][N], R[N][N];

int main(void)
{
    int x, y, z;
    char str[100];

    /* Matrix inicialization */
    for (y = 0; y < N; y++)
    {
        for (x = 0; x < N; x++)
        {
            A[y][x] = x;
            B[y][x] = y;
            R[y][x] = 0;
        }
    }

    /* Matrix multiplication */
    for (y = 0; y < N; y++)
    {
        for (z = 0; z < N; z++)
        {
            for (x = 0; x < N; x++)
            {
                R[y][x] += A[y][z] * B[z][x];
            }
        }
    }

    /* Printing result */
    for (y = 0; y < N; y++)
    {
        const char *pad = "";
        for (x = 0; x < N; x++)
        {
            sprintf(str, "%s%lli", pad, R[y][x]);
            write(1, str, strlen(str));
            pad = " ";
        }
        write(1, "\n", 1);
    }

    return(0);
}
```

I have reservations about whether the matrix multiplication algorithm is correct; I get the same value (`332833500`) printed for every cell.

Comment: I got a proof file given by the TA and it prints exactly the same value as well.

Comment: I tried redoing the multiplication algorithm and got the same result, so I guess it is kosher.  If it agrees with the TA's expected answer, so much the better.  You can get more interesting output if you use `A[y][x] = x + y; B[y][x] = x - y;` to initialize the arrays, but interesting isn't necessarily what was wanted.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I get surprissed as well about the result because it was not what I expected.